# Extracting anchor tag links from an ul list with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to extract each anchor tag link out of a menu I've set up for an online course

The ul id is #sidebar

the li's in the sidebar are in the right chapter orders, so I would like to find which chapter page the user is on and then grab the previous chapter and the next chapter, to pass to some other anchor tags at the bottom of each chapter.

This is how far I've gotten.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < $("#sidebar ul li").size(); i++) {

            console.log('chapter '+i+' = ',$("#sidebar ul li").get(i))

    }
```

This returns each li element, so how do I now grab the a href value inside each li returned?

I tried putting .a on the end , didn't work. Couldn't find much in google either.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this one: [**in fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/s5KSz/)

```
var $sidelist = $("#sidebar ul li").size();

for (var i = 0; i < $sidelist; i++) {
    console.log('chapter ' + Math.floor(i + 1) + ' = ', $("#sidebar ul li").find('a').eq(i).attr('href'));
}
```

Output of above is:

```
//this is the output of for loop:
    chapter 1 = #chaper-1
    chapter 2 = #chaper-2
    chapter 3 = #chaper-3
```

or with `$.each()`:

```
var $sidelist = $("#sidebar ul li");
$.each($sidelist, function(i, v){
   console.log('chapter '+Math.floor(i + 1)+' = ' + $(this).find('a').attr('href'));
});
```

### Note:

You have to do this `Math.floor(i + 1)` to `start the chapter with index 1 otherwise this will start at 0`.

Comment: +1 For giving examples using both OPs code and the appropriate / better alternative.

Comment: It's not a best practice to run selector in a loop.

Comment: @Jai also, you can put find('a') out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

From performance perspective, it's important to run selector just once, out of loop.

```
    var links =  $("#sidebar ul li a"); // equivalent to  $("#sidebar ul li").find('a')
    for(i = 0, length = links.length; i < length; ++i){
         console.log('chapter '+ i + ' = ' + $(links[i]).attr('href'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of FIND (),

```
for(var i = 0; i < $("#sidebar ul li").size(); i++) {
 console.log('chapter'+ i +' = ',$("#sidebar ul li").find('a').eq(i).attr('href'));
}
```

Comment: It's bad idea to run selector in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for your prompt answers,

I ended up getting this to do what I want with a bit of fiddling around.

This is what I come up with...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var previouschap;
var nextchap;
var chapter ="<?php echo (isset($_GET['chapter'])) ? $_GET['chapter'] : 'No Chapter';  ?>";

for(var i = 0; i < $("#sidebar li").size(); i++) {
    liresult = $($("#sidebar li a").get(i)).attr('href');

    if(liresult == './index.php?chapter='+chapter)
                    {
                        previouschap = $($("#sidebar li a").get(i-1)).attr('href');
                        nextchap = $($("#sidebar li a").get(i+1)).attr('href');

                        $('#previous-chapter').attr('href', previouschap);
                        $('#next-chapter').attr('href', nextchap);
                        break;
                    }

    }
});
```